# Visual Studio Code Platform IO missing icon after install

Tags: arduino

I try to install PlatformIO IDE for arduino but the icon for open app is missing. I try to reinstall app and reset program nothing.
Could You advice how to solve this issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I`m uninstall the VC use revo uninstaller and delete all registry and other connected files.  Then Install again VC and install PlatformIO. NOw it`s works